# fastest way to check if both arrays meet their own condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays containing integer values.
array 1 is true if it is more than 10.
array 2 is true if it is more than 100.

I want to find the number of indexes where both items are true as quickly as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to find first index where the condition for both arrays is True?

Comment: You mean that you want the solution as quickly as possible or your code has to run as quickly as possible? Mozway has answered just 3 minutes after the question was posted. Thats's quite quick.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably combine the two boolean arrays with a binary AND, and [`sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) to count the `True`:

```
out = ((array1>10) & (array2>100)).sum()
```